# Alert box in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there any option to show an alert box in GAE (python) that doesn't rely on javascript?

I want to show an alert box just after I do some actions on my database and just before I redirect to another page, and I'm trying to avoid javascript, (mainly becouse I dont know much about it.)

I have a html form with 2 buttons (next and back), and a text area. If the text area is empty, I want to re render the form, and if the text has something I would like to show an alert box after I update my db, and then to redirect.

```
def post(self, res1, machine_id):
  if back:
    self.redirect('/%s/%s' %(username,machine_id)
  if next:
    user, machine, avisos = self.get_username_machine(username, machine_id)
    if not text:
       msg = ' you have to input a text'
    else:
       msg = 'Call submitted'
       call = dbstructure.Call(machine_id= machine_id, text= text, rep = rep)
       call.put()
       #Browser.AlertBox("Call Submitted")
       self.redirect('/')
     self.render(page, msg=msg)
```

I tried to do some onclick on tgghe button, but I'm not able to make it work correctly.

Any one has any advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't be scared of javascript. It's really easy to learn, especially if you use a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Answer (score 0):

Make an alert-looking box and throw it somewhere in your html output.

```
<div class ="alert" style="width:200px;height:100px;background:#f00; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0 auto;">
    This is information!
</div>
```

Comment: You can add a form with a submit button, which performs the redirect.

Comment: that was what I was trying, but I need to do some checking an updating before doing the redirect. I give some extra explanation in the question

Comment: Well, I don't exactly speak python (or google app engine for that matter), but I do know the only way to change the content on a page without changing the page is javascript. If you're changing the page, just append an alert to your output, otherwise you need some javascript.